# Mill Build Tool: How to run the tests of all Modules at once?

Tags: scala, mill

I'm using *Mill* and I can't figure out how to run the tests or even compile all Modules at once.

There is `clear`, but running `mill resolve _` does not seem to have a command for it.

For now I run the tests for each Module separately.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What you mean with "There is `clear`"? Do you mean the `clean` target?

Comment: @TobiasRoeser yes running `mill clean`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit:* The Answer targets an outdated Mill version. See below for an updated version.

I assume you're talking about `ScalaModule`s and your tests are located in `test` sub-modules.

Run all tests of your project with:

```
mill __.test.test
```

The `__` is a wildcard and matches in this case any parent module(s) (like the `**` in Ant patterns). The `.test.test` matches a `test` target in a module named `test`.

To compile all modules, run:

```
mill __.compile
```

And to run all compile targets and run tests in one go, run:

```
mill all __.compile __.test.test
```

Notice, that we need to use the `all` target here, which accepts multiple targets as arguments. That's needed because mill only accepts a single target or target-pattern and treats any additional command line argument as a parameter for that target.

*Edit:*

Newer versions of Mill no longer have the `all` command. Instead, you can give multiple targets separated with `+`.

```
mill __.compile + __.test
```

Also, to run all `test` targets, it's enough to run `mill __.test`. In very older Mill versions, this results in tests running twice, but this is fixed for a long time and the workaround to use `__.test.test` is no longer needed.